# How can I import products from another site into Vocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import

How can I import products from another site into Vocommerce?

I've searched for various plugins
But they only get the file

Comment: Have you tried this plugin: [Store to WooCommerce Migration Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextcart-woocommerce-migration/)? It runs very smoothly with my store.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools->Export in that install wordpress importer. Then import products from that which will be in .xml format. Then Do the same step in the website where you want to export products. But use o tools->import and upload that .xml file.

Comment: thanks for your response.
But I don't have access to that site anymore.
I want to import products via feed or json